# How do I convert gps time to date in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently I am using

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(my_time_unix_ns/1000 AS int64)) AS my_date,...
```

But some of the columns store time in gps ns. How do I convert them into date?

Comment: What is "gps ns"?

Comment: I don't think Bigquery supports nanosecond precision for timestamps or datetime. You might have to truncate to microsecond. See description here for timestamp https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for nanosecond precision within Cloud BigQuery. BigQuery CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() returns only up to milliseconds (Example:1), and the CAST() function supports only up to millisecond precision level (#Example-2, 3 and 4).  For more context on timestamp precision, please refer to the supported range of BigQuery timestamps [1], which is 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999.

On the other hand, I assume the Unix time function you are using returns an integer value larger than the capacity of Int64. Please refer to the numeric data type documentation [2]

Example-1:

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS Current_Time

Result: 2019-12-24 17:51:44.419542 UTC

Example-2:

SELECT CAST('2019-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AS TIMESTAMP)

Result: 2019-12-24 00:00:00 UTC

Example-3:

SELECT CAST('2019-12-24 11:12:47.145482+00' AS TIMESTAMP)

Result: 2019-12-24 11:12:47.145482 UTC

Example-4:

SELECT CAST('2019-12-24 11:12:47.14548200' AS TIMESTAMP)

Result:  error: "Could not cast literal "2019-12-24 11:12:47.14548200" to type TIMESTAMP "

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#integer-type